# Deploy Java App on Heroku which depends on my own Maven artifacts

Tags: java, maven, deployment, heroku, artifactory

Heroku supports [deployment of Java apps based on Maven](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java#deploy-to-heroku)

They also [give advice](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies) for app deployment if a lib is needed that is not available in a public maven repository

But:
I have two Maven projects, where one depends on the other one. When I locally mvn install the dependent artifact I can mvn package the other one and everything works fine. However, I cannot push it to heroku, because heroku can't access my local mvn repo.

What can I do? Will it be necessary to setup a private maven repo accessible to heroku on the web (e.g. artifactory) or are there any other ways to deploy such an app with a custom dependency on heroku?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternate deployment path for Heroku called [Anvil](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-anvil) that might help here.  With this path, you would build everything locally with any private libs you need and [copy all dependencies into your target directory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html), and then use Anvil to build and release the whole thing to your Heroku app. By default, Anvil will detect your app as Java and try to build it again, but you can override this by specifiying the [null buildpack](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/null-buildpack), which tells it to take your files as is because you already did the build locally. This is probably better shown with an example:

1. Install Anvil:

   `heroku plugins:install https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-anvil`
2. Clone this example app that already has `copy-dependencies` configured in its `pom.xml`. You would need to configure this in your own app:

   `git clone git://github.com/heroku/template-java-jaxrs.git`
3. Go into the dir and build the app, which will run `copy-dependencies`.  This is critical because you need all your dependencies in your app's `target` dir, not in `~/.m2/repository` so Heroku will be able to find them:

   `mvn package`
4. Create the Heroku app:

   `heroku create`
5. Use Anvil to build with the null buildpack and release to the app:

   `heroku build -b https://github.com/ryandotsmith/null-buildpack.git -r`

Comment: sounds good Ryan! Thank you. Means, I'll have to keep /target in my git repo as well, and checkin binaries. I can live with that at the moment. Do you think I could setup artifactory (or any other repo manager) and let heroku check out my own artifacts from there? I would have to secure it propertly. Don't know if this is easy to setup, but it might be the best solution in the end if we have multiple maven dependecies in our own software. thanks a lot again!

Comment: No, you don't need to (and shouldn't) check `/target` into your git repo. Anvil (`heroku build`) uploads your artifacts via HTTP outside of git -- in fact, you could use any VCS you'd like with this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look how we do it with a live open source web app: [pom.xml](https://github.com/yegor256/s3auth/blob/master/s3auth-rest/pom.xml). The app is deployed to Heroku using Maven and Ant. We automatically do `git clone`, then copy new files into the folder, and then do `git commit && git push`. What's important is that we use `maven-invoker-plugin` in order to download artifacts inside the Heroku slug.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Maven repository. If your projects are on GitHub then you can use [JitPack](https://jitpack.io) for this. It will build your code and publish a jar.

There are instructions and docs on the website. Basically add JitPack as a repository and then add your project as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2018 I would recommend using [Heroku Maven Plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin)

It allows to build application locally and then push artefact to Heroku.
It solved my issues with local maven dependencies.

Sample configuration for Spring Boot app:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <appName>${heroku.appName}</appName>
                <processTypes>
                    <web>java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</web>
                </processTypes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If you are using [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) then `${heroku.appName}` will be automatically resolved.